# Offline replication using files

Tags: oracle, replication

Is it possible to organize asynchronous data exchange with separate files (transportable tablespaces maybe) using Oracle Streams? I.e, is it possible to organize offline replication using files?

Comment: You need to better define your question.  What end result are you hoping for?  What are your constraints?

Comment: I have 2 databases, among them set up replication using snapshots, but a channel of communication between these databases is very bad.
I want the main base formed a kind of file that contains a package of changes to the tables, procedures, and other things that I could connect to a remote database and use. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is the data exchange one-way or bidirectional?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using DataPump or imp/exp if you want to do this in batches with files.  You would use these tools to export the things you want, then get the files over to the other database and import them.

If you have a poor connection between the two hosts, however, you're going to run in to the same problem you're running in to with your snapshots and database links.  You still need to get the data across to the other box.

Oracle Streams is another option that may be able to basically queue up transactions while the link is unusable, but is a far more advanced topic and one you may want to consider hiring a consultant for.